# Kendo UI Mobile - How to display 2 listview on a view?

Tags: jquery-mobile, kendo-mobile

I want to show a view with 2 listview like this:

[image]

But when I implement by Kendo UI Mobile with:

```
 <div id="cptTab" data-role="view" data-title="Billing" data-layout="billing-layout">
        <header data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <span data-role="view-title">CPT</span>
                <a data-align="left" data-role="button" href="#censusmainTab">Census</a>
                <a data-align="right" data-role="button" data-click="onNavigateToAddCpt">+</a>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div>
            Patient:
            <label>
                <input readonly="true" class="PatientNameLabel" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>NEW CPT's</div>
        <ul data-role="listview" id="cptsListView" data-click="onCPTItemClicked" />
        <div>PREVIOUS CPT's</div>
        <ul data-role="listview" id="cptsPreviousListView" data-click="onPreviousCPTItemClicked" />
    </div>
```

But it display like this, it's missing 2nd listview (Previous listview):
[image]

Please let me know if I did something wrong or it's a bug of Kendo UI Mobile.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-type="group" id="ListView" data-click="onItemClicked"/>
```

to create two group, the first for new CPT's and the second for previous CPT's.
The function onItemClicked should change its behaviour according to which group is clicked.

[see the documentation for better details](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/listview)

Comment: Hi Morris, I tried to do that:

`<ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group">
            <li>
                NEW CPT's
                <ul data-role="listview" id="cptsListView" data-click="onCPTItemClicked" />
            </li>
            <li>
                PREVIOUS CPT's
                <ul data-role="listview" id="cptsPreviousListView" data-click="onPreviousCPTItemClicked" />
            </li>
        </ul>`

But no luck

Comment: try with: <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group"> <li> NEW CPT's <ul id="cptsListView" data-click="onCPTItemClicked"></ul></li> <li> PREVIOUS CPT's <ul id="cptsPreviousListView" data-click="onPreviousCPTItemClicked"></ul></li>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-type="group">
        <li>NEW CPT's
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a> 1 st item in 1st list view </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>PREVIOUS CPT's
            <ul>
               <li>
                    <a >1 st item in 2nd list view </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a >2nd item in 2nd list view </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>        
    </ul>
```

For live demo click [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2TkGR/9/)